# Is possible use with node sqlite3 command import txt fil and improve bulk insert?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

i am trying import csv file from node to sqlite file.

I tried following command via npm package sqlite3.

```
 var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

 db.run('.import "/Users/avito/PhpstormProjects/blog/typescript/src/app/services/workflow_temp.txt"'
        + 'INTO TABLE workflow_1_temp'
        + 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","'
        + 'ENCLOSED BY "\'"'
        + 'LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\''
        + 'IGNORE 1 ROWS'
        + ')');
```

i got this error

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ".": syntax error
```

When i am trying this via command line, that works. Is possible use sqlite3 feature with this npm package?

And is .import faster then bulk insert? I wanna improve bulk insert. When i am inserting cca 1 000 000~5 sec. Is possible write faster when i am create .txt file and then i use import via sqlite3 .import file.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  "The interactive interpreter offers a set of meta-commands" which means .import is implemented in the sqlite3 binary and not in the library that the JavaScript package uses.

Keep in mind that sqlite, by default, uses auto-commit mode, which means a transaction per statement.  If you execute a single insert per row that is slow.  You can speed things up considerable if you batch insert, say, 1000 rows at a time:

```
insert into t (c) values (v1), (v2), .... (v1000);
```